# Subsets and Proper subsets of regular language

Tags: finite-automata

Let L ⊆ {0, 1}* . Then

1) If all proper subsets of L are regular,is L regular?

2) If all finite subsets of L are regular,is L regular?

3) If a proper subset of L is not regular,is L non regular?

I am  not sure if one or more of the above are true.I think 2) is true because any finite subset can be accepted by a DFA.Are 1) and 3) always true?If not,I am not able to provide counter examples.

Answer (score 2):

1) Consider $L-\{w\}$ where $w$ is an arbitrary element of $L$. What can you conclude?

2) Remember: every finite set is regular.

3) Start with an easy example $L=\{a,b\}^*$ is regular, and contains various types of subsets.

Comment: For 2 ) ,  Li = {a^i b^i} is regular for all finite i.But union is not regular